# perf annotate is showing me only the most expensive function

Tags: linux, perf

`perf annotate` is showing me only a single function -- the most expensive according to `perf report`. I tried all the hot-keys (ENTER, ESC, H, TAB, shift-TAB) from the help screen, but I'm unable to switch to any other function.

Comment: How long did your `perf record` run for?  Maybe it only collected a handful of samples, and they were all in the hot function?  Or do you mean `perf report` does show you samples in other functions from the same perf.data you're using with annotate?

Comment: @Peter_Cordes
I run perf record for many minutes -- at least 10. And they were not only spent in the function perf annotate is showing.

perf report is showing many more.